# Choosing the right sized oil-filled radiator for a room?

Tags: radiator

Given a very small room, what are the drawbacks or advantages or using a 'medium-large' 2000w oil-filled radiator unit versus a smaller ~700w unit?

As far as I'm aware, the larger unit, whilst consuming more electricity, should neutralise this factor by retaining it's temperature for a longer amount of time (given it's greater volume of oil).

What I'm unsure of is if it is more financially economically to do this, or more or less identical to the smaller unit?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the temperature is set the same, all electric resistance heating is exactly equivalent on an "efficiency" basis - the 700W heater will run 2.87 times as long to deliver the same amount of heat, at the same exact cost.

The 700W heater is less likely to overload the circuit, if the circuit is shared.

The 2000W heater can deliver more heat if the 700W heater runs all the time yet the room is too cold. That will, of course, cost more, as it will use more power.

An electric heat pump is **far** more expensive to buy, and complex to install - but the running cost is far less, if the initial expense can be borne, so it pays off in the longer run.

Comment: I would emphases the circuit loads with the 2000 W heater.

Answer (score 1):

The larger heater will heat the room up faster.  If that means you turn it off when you leave the room it might be a lot more efficient than the small one if you would leave that on all the time because it takes too long to heat the room up initially.

IMO there is no room so small that a 700W heater would be an adequate sole source of heat in the UK, where you seem to be.  Unless you're just aiming for frost prevention or providing supplemental heat EG to one room in a house that doesn't have a central heating radiator.